# Can I set a password for ubuntu's media sharing feature?

Tags: shared-folders, media

Can I add a password to the media sharing, make it necessary to enter a password to access the files?

The media sharing option on ubuntu:

[image: media sharing option on ubuntu]

Here I can view the shared media on a different computer:

[image: Here i can view the shared media on a different computer]

Comment: Looks like you should look into installing and configuring samba.

Comment: I never used it but I think this new media sharing feature is a bare bones DNLA server so it's just ON or OFF, no password or advanced features.

Comment: Thanks all, yes it appears to just be on or off, also I've got samba all sorted out now and its working great, even better than the other method could have been!